# ASP.NET MVC rendering seems slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created a brand new MVC4 web application in Visual Studio, and done nothing more with it than add a Home controller and a "Hello world" index view for it.  I then installed the MiniProfiler NuGet package and put the necessary couple of lines in `_Layout.cshtml`.  This is what I get when I run the site in Release mode (hosted in IIS):

[image: MVC rendering picture]

The rendering time varies by pageload, but 130ms is about as fast as it gets.  This seems a bit slow to me, as I've seen other people who get pages rendered in 30ms or quicker.  Any ideas why the rendering would be this slow with a brand new empty MVC4 project?  My processor is an Intel Core i5-2400 and the machine has 16GB RAM.

By the way, this is *not* the first time the page is loaded; I reloaded the page a few times before getting this 130ms result.

**UPDATE:**
I followed the advice in the answer from PSCoder (remove all but the RazorViewEngine), and it halved the rendering time:

[image: MVC rendering picture 2]

This is really good, but I still get about 70ms or higher for the main `Render` action of the page; ideally I'd like to halve that or better.

Specifically, I'd like to ask:

- Does this rendering time seem overly slow or is it average for my machine?
- Is there any way I can speed it up?

Comment: The only unknown you mentioned is the profiler tool itself. Maybe eliminate that, and use a console app to make a `HttpClient` or `WebClient` or whatever you want, to download the page normally, then see how long it actually takes. Run it in a loop a few dozen or hundred times and record the times there manually.

Comment: @Joe Except I've seen other screenshots where people use MiniProfiler and get 30ms renderings.

Comment: Can you make a better screenshot?  It's very hard to read and is full of unnecessary blank space.

Comment: @Amy OK I improved it.

Comment: What are you running this on?  The development server?  IIS Express?  IIS 6?  IIS7? 7.5? 8?

Comment: @MystereMan It's running on IIS7.

Comment: @Jez can you also try run the application in release mode and change your Web.config entry compilation debug="true" to "false"

Comment: @PSCoder That didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Ok. i was thinking about the default viewlocationcaching which gets kicked in on release mode...

Comment: Actually - What IS in your view?!

Comment: Mines coming in at 6s!

Comment: I made a HelloWorld page that rendered in 14 seconds.  I cannot even imaging wtf it is doing... LOC=20170608-10:31:18.131,UTC=20170608-09:31:18.131,DELTA=22357,THR=App,DEBUG,LOG=App,DQ=000000,NQ=000000,NQUTC=09:31:18.131,NQTHR=007,App,Compilation of the generated code for the Razor file at '/Views/HelloWorld/Index.cshtml' started.
LOC=20170608-10:31:32.957,UTC=20170608-09:31:32.957,DELTA=37184,THR=App,DEBUG,LOG=App,DQ=000000,NQ=000000,NQUTC=09:31:32.957,NQTHR=007,App,Compilation of the generated code for the Razor file at '/Views/HelloWorld/Index.cshtml' completed in 14824.1328ms.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This could help improve ASP.NET MVC related performance issue , one performance improvement that you can do is to clear all the view engines and add the one(s) that you use. say for  ex:- `RazorViewEngine`. MVC registers 2 view engines by default `Webforms` and `Razor` view engines, so clearing and adding the ones that is used alone will improve the look up performance.

You can add this in `global.asax` `Application_Start`.

```
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();    
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

In order to completely utilize view look up caching and thus again performance gain compile the code in release mode and make sure that your `web.config` file is configured with `<compilation debug="false" />` for view look up caching to kick in.

Comment: This helps performance, but to add to this answer, a ball-and-chain around my site's leg was `System.Web.Optimization` beta 2 which was really slowing everything down, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302406/setting-debug-false-actually-causing-far-slower-rendering).  After upgrading that package my site is much faster.

Comment: Thats really weird though, but good that you found where the issue lies and was able to resolve the performance issue... :)

Comment: what about using [asynchronous partial views](http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/11/13/improve-perceived-performance-of-asp-net-mvc-websites-with-async-partialviews/) or [Creating Asynchronous Actions](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/creating-asynchronous-actions-in-asp.net-mvc.htm) in mvc ?

Comment: @PSL does this still apply to MVC 5 ?

Answer (score 59):

Adding to @PSL 's answer - we only ever check for `.CSHTML files

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();

IViewEngine razorEngine = new RazorViewEngine() { FileExtensions = new string[] { "cshtml" } };

ViewEngines.Engines.Add(razorEngine);
```

Also, make sure you are running in `Release Mode` - that is absolutely critical, as ASP/Razor/MVC '**applies some pretty aggressive caching**' when in release mode

`<compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="false">` in your `Web.Config` file.

Sam Saffron/Stack Overflow looked into view rendering performance also:

http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/08/16/Oh+view+where+are+thou+finding+views+in+ASPNET+MVC3+

Answer (score 0):

Views are compiled before use - so on the first occasion they are slow.

Subsequently they are recompiled if the `.cshtml` file changes - which means the directories that views are stored in are being monitored. So hard disk speed will be a factor for MVC views.

Even if they do nothing, each rendering engine checks the hard disk for `.cshtml` or `.aspx` files. Since removing a rendering engine made it run twice as fast, I suspect disk speed is the problem:

- Views are stored on a network drive, or
- Hard disk is very slow

Answer (score 0):

Pre-compile the views to speed up the first-time rendering..

Check the below blog..

https://blog.deltacode.be/2017/01/08/fix-slow-startup-of-asp-net-mvc-5-on-azure-app-services/

[image]